# Not receiving get parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using **ASP.NET MVC 5**

I'm having issues with both routes and parameters.

I have this function in my **ControllerBase**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/obtenerAngulos/{Conex_AT}/{Conex_BT}")]
public JsonResult obtenerAngulos(string Conex_AT, string Conex_BT)
{
    return Json(
        new
        {
            AT = Conex_AT,
            BT = Conex_BT
        }
        , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And I start having problems receiving the second parameter `Conex_BT` the `Url.Action()` returns this route `http://localhost:53645/Base/obtenerAngulos?Conex_AT=Y&amp;Conex_BT=y` the problem, is `Conex_BT` is always null

Then I try to work with route and add the Data Anotation for it `[Route("~/obtenerAngulos/{Conex_AT}/{Conex_BT}")]` but with `Url.Action()` I keep getting the same route as before.

Even if I try to write it manually like `http://localhost:53645/Base/obtenerAngulos/AA/BB` I get

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

I mention both problems because I'm pretty sure they are relationated.

Here is the route configuration

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );


}
```

Comment: What does `http://localhost:53645/obtenerAngulos/AA/BB` return?

Comment: @mjwills I use default routes, because i never need it before, for now it must return `{"AT":"AA","BT":"BB"}` for example, when i be able to recive both parameters i will work with the logic, thanks for response!

Comment: I am struggling to understand how that comment relates to either of the questions that I asked.

Comment: Have you enabled attribute routing on the route collection? `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` 
Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: Attribute route need to be enabled before convention based routes.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for response! how i must enable it?

Comment: @mjwills I mean, my routes are by default; `/Controller/MethodName/{parameter}` and they are working!

Comment: Do not edit your question to show the correct code after the answer has been added (I have rolled back your changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled attribute routing on the route collection.

```
//enable attribute routes
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); 

//convention-based routes
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This now means that the following should match `obtenerAngulos/y/x`

```
public class  ControllerBase: Controller {
    //Matches obtenerAngulos/y/x
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/obtenerAngulos/{Conex_AT}/{Conex_BT}")]
    public JsonResult obtenerAngulos(string Conex_AT, string Conex_BT) {
        //...
    }
}
```

The tilde (~) on the method attribute is used to override any route prefixes if needed.

Routes are matched in the route table in the same order they are added. In your example you had convention based routes registered before attribute routes. Once a route is matched it no longer looks for other matches.

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: I try enabling it, but i keep getting 404, thanks for take time to help me!